# Describe a statistical model for the observed data

Tags: probability, statistics

A random sample of three observations $(X_1, X_2, X_3)$ is generated from a $Binomial(n = 2, \theta)$ distribution where $\theta \in (0, 1)$ unknown, but only $T = X_1 + X_2 + X_3$ is observed by the statistician.

$(a)$ Describe a statistical model for the observed data

MY ANS:

The random variable

$\sum_{i=1}^{3} X_i$ ~ $Bernoulli(\theta)$

The probability model

$$f_{\theta}(t) = (\theta)(1-\theta)$$

WHERE $t = 0,1,\cdots, n$

not sure what I'm doing

---

SOLUTION:

$T$ ~ $Bin(2 + 2 + 2, \theta), \theta \in (0, 1)$, $f_{\theta}(t) = {6 \choose t} \theta^t (1-\theta)^{6-t}$ for $t \in {0,1,2,3,4,5,6}$

I don't really understand it to be honest. Shouldn't you find what the I.I.D for binomial is, which is bernoulli?

Comment: Hint: a binomial random variable with parameters $n$ and $p$ can be interpreted as the sum of $n$ iid random variables with parameter $p$.

Comment: *$n$ iid Bernoulli random variables